# Add a if statement to a notification in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, timer, notifications, alert

Right now my code presents a alert message immediately when the app loads. I would like to change the code to only display the alert message. If the button is not pressed within 20 seconds of loading. The button action is called `pressBUTTON`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let myNotification = Notification.Name(rawValue:"MyNotification")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let nc = NotificationCenter.default
    nc.addObserver(forName:myNotification, object:nil, queue:nil, using:catchNotification)
}
    @IBAction func pressBUTTON(_ sender: Any) {
    }

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let nc = NotificationCenter.default
    nc.post(name:myNotification,
            object: nil,
            userInfo:["message":"Hello there!", "date":Date()])
}

func catchNotification(notification:Notification) -> Void {
    print("Catch notification")

    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let message  = userInfo["message"] as? String,
        let date     = userInfo["date"]    as? Date else {
            print("No userInfo found in notification")
            return
    }

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Notification!",
                                  message:"\(message) received at \(date)",
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your alert code inside a non-repeating `Timer` with a 20 seconds delay. In your `pressBUTTON` function, call `invalidate` on such timer to disable the notification from showing.

Might be a good idea to invalidate the timer when leaving your view controller as well (e.g., in the `viewWillDisapear` method).